# How to change the color of the braces in sublime text 3 without plugin?

Tags: sublimetext3

How to change the color of the braces in sublime text 3 **without plugin** ?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edit ( *or add* ) these settings in your active `tmTheme` file:

```
<key>bracketsForeground</key>
<string>#D80E64</string>

<key>bracketsOptions</key>
<string>foreground</string>

<key>bracketContentsForeground</key>
<string>#D80E64</string>

<key>bracketContentsOptions</key>
<string>underline</string>
```

---

`bracketsForeground` & `bracketsOptions` affect brackets that are directly adjacent to the caret:

[image: foreground]

`bracketContentsForeground` & `bracketContentsOptions` affect the innermost level of brackets that surround the text adjacent to the caret:

[image: contents]

Comment: This only works if the cursor is directly adjacent to a bracket, though.

Comment: @Enteleform Thanks, but this method does not work when cursor outside of the block

Comment: @JimButton : So you want your brackets to always be a specific color? I don't think that's possible without a plugin or custom syntax, because brackets do not have their own scope. They share the `source` scope along with most of the code in your files.

Answer (score 1):

Enteleform's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36972252/1426065) works if the cursor is directly next to a parenthesis, square bracket, or curly brace, but not otherwise. Having all of these highlighted regardless of cursor position without a separate plugin is not possible with the default Java syntax that ships with Sublime. In order to color an item with your color scheme (`.tmTheme` file), it needs to have a unique [scope](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html#scopes) defined in the language's syntax definition (`.tmLanguage` or `.sublime-syntax` file).

For example, in Python, the following defines a list:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

In the Python syntax definition, the opening and closing square brackets `[ ]` are scoped as `punctuation.definition.list.begin.python` and `punctuation.definition.list.end.python`, respectively. You could then add a rule to your color scheme like so:

```xml
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>List Brackets</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.python punctuation.definition.list</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>background</key>
        <string>#FFFFFF</string>
        <key>fontStyle</key>
        <string>bold italic</string>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#19FFF0</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

However, the Java syntax does not contain a similar set of scopes for all brackets, so unless you use a plugin like [`BracketHighlighter`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BracketHighlighter), the behavior you desire is just not possible.

Comment: Thank you , I do not find the settings for the brackets in `.sublime-syntax` file too